# Azure Functions - Access To Path Is Denied

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am getting the following error when running the published version of my function, it should be noted that when I run this locally it works correctly.

> Access to the path 'D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.12205\wkhtmltopdf' is denied. at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String
>   path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) at
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean
>   checkHost) at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path) at
>   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.EnsureWkHtmlLibs() at
>   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdfInternal(WkHtmlInput[]
>   htmlFiles, String inputContent, String coverHtml, String
>   outputPdfFilePath, Stream outputStream) at
>   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent,
>   String coverHtml, Stream output) at
>   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent,
>   String coverHtml) at
>   NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(String htmlContent)
>   at HTMLtoPDF.Function1.d__0.MoveNext()

My application basically transforms HTML into a PDF file, uploads to azure and returns the result uri.

As you can see in my code below I don't make any references to this path.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using NReco.PdfGenerator;
using System;

namespace HTMLtoPDF
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string pdfurl = "";
            // parse query parameter
            string html = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "html", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (html == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                html = data?.html;
            }
            try
            {
                HtmlToPdfConverter converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
                var genpdf = converter.GeneratePdf(html);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(genpdf, writable: false);
                 pdfurl = await UploadFileAsBlobAsync(stream, Guid.NewGuid()+".pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             pdfurl = ex.Message+Environment.NewLine+ex.InnerException;
            }

            return html == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass html on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, pdfurl);
        }
        public static async Task<string> UploadFileAsBlobAsync(Stream stream, string filehtml)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(HIDDENFORSECURITY);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("applicationimages");

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filehtml);

           await  blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

            stream.Dispose();
            return blockBlob?.Uri.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the exception ?  Do you have stacktrace ?

Comment: The filesystem in functions is done via an azure storage account so there aren't drive letters to start with. 

That path doesn't exist on my machine where it works so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: @ManojChoudhari added to question

Answer (score 1):

Looks like NReco PdfConverter uses wkhtmltopdf.exe under the hood to generate the PDF and when calling `NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter.EnsureWkHtmlLibs()` it is getting the access denied exception.

See here for possible resolution:
https://github.com/nreco/nreco/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in below two lines.  It is trying to create folders on file system.
When you host your program in Azure, folder permitted

```
HtmlToPdfConverter converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
var genpdf = converter.GeneratePdf(html);
```

Can you use the stream variant of GeneratePdf which dos not generate any intermittent folder.

Comment: That's not true, it returns a byte array no folders or files involved

Comment: @Alec. - you can check the error in stack trace: **at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path) at **